# Trying to compile only filtered data from a number of workbooks together

Tags: vba, excel

I've written this piece of code to try and collate a large number of Excel workbooks together. Ordinarily the code would pick up ALL data in the workbooks, but I've asked it to only select data which has already been filtered and is now visible. Sounds great, right? Unfortunately it doesn't save all of the data to the new workbook! For example, if a workbook has cell values 1, 2900 and 2901 filtered and visible (3 visible rows, though the cell references could be B1, B2000, B9999 etc), the code will paste in all three lines to the composite workbook, then save over the final two lines with data from the next workbook in the sequence! I imagine it's something to do with the row number--I think I've told the code to select all highlighted data but only create an insufficient amount of rows to save it all. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks all.

```
Sub MergeDuplicatedDataFromWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

 FolderPath = "MY PATH"

NRow = 1

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

Do While FileName <> ""
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName


 Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
  Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
   SourceRange.Columns.Count)

DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value


    SourceRange.Copy DestRange

    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

 WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

 FileName = Dir()
Loop

 End Sub
```

Comment: SourceRange is not defined in that code.

Comment: Why is the command

    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

above but

    Filename = Dir()

...below?  Shouldn't they both be the same?

Answer (score 0):

`DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value` copies values only. `SourceRange.Copy DestRange` copies values AND formats. No need to use both. In this case `.Copy` is recommended to handle filter. `.Resize` is needed when using `.Value` type of copy, now it can be omitted because `.Copy` does it for you, all you need to do is to specify the top left cell of the target range. 
Try this:

```
SourceRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy SummarySheet.Cells(NRow, 2)
NRow = Cells(NRow, 2).End(xlDown).Row + 1
```